# Div Position Inline Block

Tags: html, css

I want 2 div show inline block with this code below

```css
.imgcss {
 height:300px;
 width:200px;
 background-color:#CCC;
 display:inline-block}
.tablecss {
 display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="imgcss">
    
    </div>
    <div class="tablecss">
    <table width="auto" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>USER1</td>
    <td>2000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>USER2</td>
    <td>2005</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>USER3</td>
    <td>2010</td>
  </tr>
</table>

    </div>
</div>
```

But It don't show like I want. You can see this picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPayZ.jpg

I want it show like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyKDl.jpg

How to do it ? Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `vertical-align: top` to `.tablecss`. `inline-block` sets the object to the `baseline` by default:

```
.imgcss {
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:#CCC;
  display:inline-block
}

.tablecss {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top; <----
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pc9308fc/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.imgcss {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top; /* <-- add this */
}
.tablecss {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imgcss">

  </div>
  <div class="tablecss">
    <table width="auto" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>USER1</td>
        <td>2000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>USER2</td>
        <td>2005</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>USER3</td>
        <td>2010</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
.tablecss {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `vertical-align:top` to your class `.tablecss`

**CSS**
    .tablecss {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:top;
    }